# how do I charge all items in a cart array at the same time in stripe checkout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I have been trying to figure this out for a full week now. using stripe, how do I present the user with all of the items that they put in their cart in my nextjs e-commerce store.I can get it to work with one item as long as I don't do anything to try and change that item. as soon as I do anything to try and change the item I don't get any errors but the localhost reloads on the button press and I see an empty cart page. I have tried at least 6 different tutorials and contacted the stripe developer support 3 times. nothing has worked so here is my current relevant front end code:

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
);

function Checkout() {
  const [basket, addToBasket] = useAppContext();
  const {data: session} = useSession();
  const [id, setId] = useState([]);
  const [price, setprice] = useState([]);
  const [description, setdescription] = useState([]);
  const [title, settitle] = useState([]);

  const updateState = () => {
    setId(basket.id);
    setdescription(basket.description);
    setprice(basket.price);
    settitle(basket.title);
  }

  //send data to the api

    const postData = async () => {  
      const response = await fetch("/api/checkout_sessions", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(
          id,
          price,
          description,
          title,
        ),
      });
      return response.json();
    };
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Check to see if this is a redirect back from Checkout
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (query.get('success')) {
      console.log('Order placed! You will receive an email confirmation.');
    }

    if (query.get('canceled')) {
      console.log('Order canceled -- continue to shop around and checkout when youre ready.');
    }
  }, []);
  return (
   <form onSubmit={() => {
        updateState;
         postData;
            }} >
   <button 
   type="submit"
   role="link"
   className="button"
   >                       
   proceed to checkout
 </button>
                    </form>
)}
```

here is my current backend that is supposed to send my user to the cart to make their purchase. like I said at the start what happens is I have items in my basket and I press the checkout button but everything reloads and I stay at the cart page.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const items = req.body.id
    const amount = req.body.price
    const description = req.body.description
    const title = req.body.title 

// var priceVariable ='price_1MB8P4FqoomU2P4qrVmtxCvp';
  
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        // shipping_options: ["shr_1MBn0HFqoomU2P4qZk4vqOQ3"],
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ["US", "CA", "GB"],
        },
       line_items:[{
        price: items,
        quantity: 1,
          price_data: { 
            currency: 'usd',
            unit_amount: amount,
            product_data: {  
              description: description,
              name: title,
            }},
       }],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      });
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

thanks for the help y'all